# Which directories does macOS update while upgrading macOS?

Tags: macos

`Install macOS Mojave.app` is so large(6GB), and the following directories is all directories that macOS have, is that all these directories will be write new system files into? Cause services that I install by Homebrew in `/usr/local/Cellar` are all remain in there, they will not be override, I just curious about where on earth the updates writes into.

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 181 root  admin   5.7K  4 19 14:54 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+  66 root  wheel   2.1K  4 10 13:49 Library
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel    64B  9 25  2018 Network
drwxr-xr-x@   5 root  wheel   160B  9 21  2018 System
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  admin   192B  9 25  2018 Users
drwxr-xr-x+   5 root  wheel   160B  4 19 14:54 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@  37 root  wheel   1.2K  4  7 20:14 bin
drwxrwxr-t    2 root  admin    64B  9 25  2018 cores
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   4.5K  4  7 20:16 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11B  9 25  2018 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     1B  4 19 14:45 home
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   313B  8 18  2018 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  wheel     1B  4 19 14:45 net
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel   192B  9 25  2018 private
drwxr-xr-x@  64 root  wheel   2.0K  4  7 20:14 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11B  9 25  2018 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@   9 root  wheel   288B  4  7 20:07 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11B  9 25  2018 var -> private/var
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being glib here but to answer your question succinctly, any directory that *needs* to be updated.

It will vary from update to update depending on what Apple wants/needs to update in the version of the OS you have and what version you are updating.

Apple has a built in command line utility to examine packages

`pkgutil`

That can be used to examine the contents of packages, extract them, etc.

You can also right-click on the package and select "Show package contents..." and browse the contents of the updater in the Finder.

A bit of googling will turn up programs that let you examine packages via a GUI. That can be helpful as packages often have the updated binaries listed in the directory trees they will be going into.

Unfortunately there is no canonical list of what directories get changed when doing updates to macOS. That is purely dependent on what is being updated.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention, is there exists some `system` controlled directory that not belongs to the `/`(root)  directory？Somewhere we can not reach and only the `system` use it?

Comment: any and **ALL** directories are up for grabs, including that one. If you get yourself a (free) Apple Developer account you'll have access to documentation on macOS. Presumably including what everything in every directory does. Me I just support 'em and if I hear somebody mucking about in those directories I either walk away or advise they reinstall macOS and **then** walk away.